# json_encode() returns blank string only when debugging through netbeans 8.0

Tags: php, netbeans, json

I developed a jQuery code which makes ajax request to the PHP and returns json output. I have executed this code hundreds of times and it works fine. Today I wanted to debug my code using Netbeans and I found that json_encode() function is returning blank string, my ajax request's error function executed with an error "Internal Server Error". I removed debugging and executed code and it runs fine without any error.

PHP Code :

```
            $r = $sth->fetchAll();

            if (count($r) > 0)
            {
                $jsonOutput = json_encode($r);  //at this step $jsonOutput is blank.
                echo $jsonOutput;
            }
```

I checked following things,

a) display_errors flag is On. I did it On/Off no use.
b) I did utf8_encode but no use.

Comment: so you receive no errors at all?

Comment: Hi Alex, When I run code, I receive no errors. When I debug, I get "Internal Server Error"